# typing an array where i know the type of the first value but but i don't know the array length neither the type of all other value

Tags: typescript

I have the following function which takes any number of arguments. However, I know the first argument must be a function, other arguments could be anything and i don't know the length of the array.
What shape should i give to the array type of known 1st element but unknown length and types for other?

```
// i tried also ...args: [Function, any], but eslint does not like the generic 'Function' type and throw an error

function test(...args: Array<????>) {
 const [callbackFn, ...restOfArgs] = args;
 // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split off the first argument then use the "..." syntax to capture the rest of the arguments. Replace the `() => void` with whatever your callback function type is.

```
function test(callbackFunction: () => void, ...args: unknown[]): void {
  callbackFunction()
  // access the rest of the arguments as you would from an array
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQARwKYGc4AoYCGANkQEYEwDWAYtPMlAFyq4CUqAvAHyoBuSCACYAaVADoJBAE4BzLM2iUoSAO5QA2gF1WzfkNQBvUKlSES5KrViIUbUAF9QQA

EDIT: I realized that I did not fully answer the question. If you'd like to keep the arguments all under the same variable, you can do so as follows:

```
function test(...args: [() => void, ...unknown[]]): void {
  args[0]()
}
```